# A circuit with displays

Tags: visual

Here is a puzzle I drew some time ago.

The answer is a single word.

[image]

Comment: What’s the goal?

Comment: @JonathanHarbaugh I've clarified that the answer is one word, thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answer is

> **ECHO**

The wiring is as follows:

> ```
> [1+2+3]
> [ 1+2 ]   [2+3]
> [1+3+4]   [3+4]
> [1+2+4]
> ```

The already-lit panels seem to be complete, which indicates

> ```
> Wire 1 = Both left segments
> Wire 2 = Top and bottom segment
> Wire 3 = Middle segment
> Wire 4 = Both right segments
> ```

Put them all together and on the left four panels you get

> [E]
> [C]
> [H]
> [O]

Answer (score 0):

Here are some observations:

> It seems that each signal corresponds to some subset of the segments, with each display combining the segments in some way. My initial guess is that each display shows the segments that exactly one of the input signals contains.
> The two displays on the right respectively combine signals 2,3 and 3,4. Since adding 1 to either of these results in no segments lighting up, all of the segments in these two displays must be contained in signal 1. This leaves the two left segments of signal 1 undetermined, for a total of four possibilities. Trying all four, the only combination gives a recognizable symbol for all signals is 
> Signal 1: 3
> Signal 2: H
> Signal 3: O
> Signal 4: E
> But I'm pretty sure 3HOE isn't a word, so perhaps I've made a faulty assumption somewhere or there's another way to extract the answer.

Comment: Perhaps (ROT13) gur jbeq vf FUBR?